# Livewire generating a collection on mount, but an array on refresh

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a (relatively) simple Livewire controller which, on mount() generates a collection of games, grouped by their start dates, and assigns it to the $games public property.

```
public $games;
protected $rules = [];
...
public function mount() {
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $games = Game::where('start', '>', $now)->orderBy('start', 'ASC')->get();
    $games = $games->groupBy(function($item) {
        return $item->start->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    })->collect();
    $this->games = $games;
}
```

The corresponding component then loops through the dates, outputs the date, and then sends the games themselves to a Blade component (irrelevant styling removed):

```
@foreach($games as $date => $thegames)
    <div>
        {{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date)->format("l jS \of F Y - g:i A") }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <x-individual.game :allgames="$thegames" :user="Auth::user()"></x-individual.game>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

The Blade component then loops through the games that it's been given and renders each of them (simplified below) :

```
@foreach($allgames as $game)
    <div>
        <div>
            <h3>
            {{ $game->game->name }}
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Within that component (not shown) are wire:click buttons which may add a person to the game, or remove them. That, in turn, fires the refresh() function of the original Livewire component, which is identical to the mount() function save that it emits the refreshComponent event at the end :

```
public function refreshThis() {
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $games = Game::where('start', '>', $now)->get();
    $games = $games->groupBy(function($item) {
        return $item->start->format("Y-m-d");
    })->collect();
    $this->games = $games;
    $this->emit('refreshComponent');
}
```

That's where the problem starts. Rather than re-render the component, as it should, it generates an error of "Attempt to read property "game" on array" within the blade component :

```
{{ $game->game->name }}
```

and sure enough, at that point, $game is now an array, not an Eloquent object (or whatever it was first time around).

If I manually refresh the page, the changes are shown without issue. But why is it issuing me an array on refreshing, and (more importantly) how can I stop it?

Comment: Refresh will not call ``mount()`` again. From the docs: mount() is only ever called when the component is first mounted and will not be called again even when the component is refreshed or rerendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the `$games` to the render method instead and it will `refresh` the data:

```php
public function render()
{
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $games = Game::where('start', '>', $now)->orderBy('start', 'ASC')->get();
    $games = $games->groupBy(function($item) {
        return $item->start->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    })->collect();

    return view('livewire.your_component_view', [
        'games' => $games
    ]);
}
```

Then refresh the component (in your main component):

```php
public function refreshThis() {
    $this->render();
}
```

If you are calling refresh from a child component you can call it form there:
Child component:

```php
$this->emit('refreshThis');
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick, thanks, although I did have to collect() the games in my render method with : 

        $this->allgames = $games->collect();